# Storing whole objects in BinarySearchTree c#

Tags: c#, object, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to use a Binary Tree to store objects, but cant figure out how to fully fit them.

Say have an `Object1 Foo = new Object1(string nameID, string phoneNumber, string classification)`

The below snippit uses an IComparable (apart of the node) to be able to compare the node values, which are based on the object nameID (with direct accessing Foo.NameID or through a function Foo.getID()), however, doing this I am then unable to access all the other info stored by the object as only the ID is stored in the tree. I have tried versions that store the ID and Object together but that didn't work very well, so i went back to this as a basis.

Which is part of the node add which checks for the left node, using soley an object store, i cant figure out how to compare if the node would fit left or right (thus the ID).

```
    public class Node {
        public IComparable item;
        public Node left;
        public Node right;

        public Node(IComparable item) {
            this.item = item;
            left = null;
            right = null;
        }

        public IComparable Item {
            get { return item; }
            set { item = value; }
        }
    }


    public class BinaryTree {
    // some other functions and stuff...

    public void AddNodeFunction(IComparable item, Node node) {
    // sort out if there is a root etc etc

    Node thisNode = root;
    if (item.CompareTo(node.Item) == -1) {
        if (thisNode.left == null) {
            Node newNode = new Node(item);
            thisNode.left = newNode;
            addComplete = true;
        } else { thisNode = thisNode.left;}
    }
    // more stuff...
    }
```

How would I go about storing the entire object (in relation to figuring out if the node should go left or right), but still being able to retrieve it? i currently have a boolean find on values, so that shoudln't be too hard to rig up to return the object, but would it be best to directly modify that object if needed (how if possible) or best to simply delete and re-add with the new info without using a list.

TDLR; how exactly do i store entire object in a Binary Tree

Comment: What exactly is type of node.Item in your code? Is it your contact object, or just a string for the name? As long as your contact object has a CompareTo that compares based on the name, this code should just work with the complete objects.

Comment: What do you mean by "Say have an `object(string nameID, string phoneNumber, string classification)`"?  Can you show us your type definition - both the properties and your implementation of `IComparable` (which, I'm assuming is what you mean by `ICompare`)?

Comment: @Fltdog57 added a bit more, and yes i meant comparable.

Comment: @Rup its an object created with a few strings and ints, but the "identifying key/ID" of the object is retrieved more or less with a return by Foo.getID(); I thought it would work with an entire object, but I am unable to add a node unless I use Foo.getID() rather than using just Foo (the whole object), but if i place it in using Foo.getID(), i lose all the other data stored in that object because only the ID gets stored, the object is created from a series of user inputs with ReadLine() and multiple forms of parsing for correct data types (a user will always put in the wrong data if allowed).

Comment: There's nothing in there that says you have to use Foo.getID(), as long as it implements the untyped IComparable. However, I'd make the whole thing generic: `public class Node<T> where T : IComparable<T>`, ditto the same type and constraint on BinaryTree, then make your item a T.

Answer (score 0):

Give up and just make the binary tree to the object type and make a binary tree for each object type.

Comment: No, this is possible e.g. here's your code (with the generic tweak I suggested) working for me - https://gist.github.com/RupW/ab2820689c1ae7eb7895971549b70ab2 . There's nothing much wrong with what you've got already, though: I'd guess it's something to do with the logic assembling the tree. That all said, knowing when to give up and try something else is a good skill too, but this problem is solveable.